# How to troubleshoot root cause of ERROR_IO (-7) in onReceivedError

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview, webviewclient, adobe-analytics

My WebView based code is too long (and scattered across several modules) to post here, and I am looking for a *general technique* that may be helpful to others anyway, so here goes:

I have a set of [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and [JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) derived classes that implement a basic web browser. It seems to be working pretty well, except that on websites running [Omniture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omniture), on a one phone only (Nexus One running CyanogenMod 6 (Android 2.2.1), a [loadUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29) with a url that exceeds a certain (reasonable) length will **freeze**, then eventually will time out with [onReceiveError()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), ERROR_IO ([-7](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#ERROR_IO)) with the following description string:

> The server failed to communicate. Try again later.

To clarify: Same exact code, same exact URL works flawlessly on all other phones that I have tested.

I could have shrugged this off by attributing this anomaly to a bug in the particular version of [android.webkit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html) in that phone, but I somehow suspect that I may be missing something in my own code that can workaround this. The reason is that on the same exact phone, the WebView-based stock browser doesn't exhibit this problem.

Curious and meticulous that I am, I find this intriguing and challenging, perhaps a great opportunity to delve deeper into some HTTP protocol debug techniques.

For example, if I had a way to tap into [android.net.http](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/package-summary.html) to get diagnostic log messages, that would have been super, but how to I do that for WebView and WebViewClient?

Any suggestions or tips on how to troubleshoot this?